# Data Studio resumir el conteo de muchas respuestas en una sola

Tags: count, charts, google-data-studio, fieldset

Tengo una base de datos con una pregunta que se repite varias veces pero las respuestas varian. son respuestas de selección. Per ejemplo: hoy de que proyecto hablaste a, b, c, d, e; así se repite la pregunta varias veces porque puede ser que en un día se hablo de varios proyectos. Al final, en data studio quiero poner una grafica de pie que me diga cuantas veces se hablo de un proyecto pero que me de la suma de todas las preguntas. Existe alguna función dentro de dato studio que me de la suma del conteo de cada proyecto de cada respuesta en un solo campo?

Comment: Hola, haz el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).